# Nicotine concentration in e-liquids

Tags: titration

E-liquids are blends of nicotine, propylene glycol, vegetable glycerin, and aroma.
I need to develop a method for determining the concentration of nicotine in a vial.
(to verify if the information listed on the bottle are correct.)

Does anyone have any idea how to proceed?

Comment: Which analytical equipment is available?

Comment: Gas chromatography would be an obvious choice.

Comment: I tested the gas chromatography but the curve I get is polluted by aromas. currently there a way to separate ?

Comment: Maybe my first idea was just a bad one. In this [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chroma.2013.02.078) on the determination of nicotine _traces_ in "nicotine-free" e-liquids, HPLC was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicotine concentration is a serious concern, as the material is a serious poison (dose matters).  Liquid Chromatography/Tandem Mass Spectrometry is a little pricey.

http://oxfordchemserve.com/e-cigarette-refill-nicotine-quantitative-test-kit/ 
  Specific test kit "designed with the non-chemist in mind" 
http://oxfordchemserve.com/wp-content/uploads/products_img/Oxford_Nicotine_Test.pdf 
   Explanation - it is a pH titration of nicotine base. 
http://www.eliquidtest.com/ 
   Another titration kit.  Google for the product spectrum.

Saliva or urine nicotine test kits detect nicotine persistent metabolite cotinine and are therefore irrelevant.

http://www.medpagetoday.com/Pulmonology/Smoking/44238 
Warning about E-liquid refills.  
http://www.veppocig.com/product_images/uploaded_images/eliquid-nicotine-strength-guide-2.png 
Claimed dosage guide.  **Caveat emptor.** 
http://www.learn.eversmoke.com/nicotine-strength.html 
A second dosage opinion.

Glycerin can pyrolyze to acrolein.  This is not a good thing to inhale.  NEVER inhale butter flavor.  Butanedione destroys lungs: "popcorn lung," bronchiolitis obliterans, obliterative bronchiolitis, constrictive bronchiolitis are life-threatenting, cumulative, and irreversible.

Comment: Thanks you for these links. Do you know the accurency of the first test?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer.  It also depends on the skill of the user at all stages.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a quantitative method witch can determine in the same time the quantity of all component, gas chromatography is good way. Only mass spectrometry detection can resolve aroma problems on your curves.

The most complicate aspect is chromatographic conditions : column, temperature...
I don't know the best column for these compounds (propylene glycol, glycerin and nicotine).

Maybe someone can help you to determine how to start your method on GC.

;)